# how to open an attachment in a webview in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry

I have designed an Application which would open in a webview(in the sense the user cannot be able to save or forward any of the webpages in my application). The issue is that whenever my application contains some link(might come from the application server) and when i open that link which may be a doc file or xls etc...that file is opening in a normal browser.. How to make that file to open in my application's webview itself?

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry's equivalent of webview is BrowserField. In order to open a file in an application's webview, you can try something like:

```
BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
            myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

add(browserField);
browserField.requestContent("http://www.blackberry.com");
```

Provide your own document link and use this to open a document/page in the app.

Comment: where to provide the link?...i have did the same opening my application in a webview..but here the requirement is when a link(attachment present in the application) is clicked, then that attachment should be opened in the webview, not in the default browser

Comment: the link has to be provided in the browserField.requestContent("link")

Comment: So save the link returned from the server as a string value and pass it in here.

Comment: how can we do that?..because the data coming from the server is dynamically changing..we are not sure at which place the link would be coming..I guess there would be an browser session or something like that?.. but im not sure

Comment: When you are requesting data from the server, you are making a connection to the server. Once the connection is made, the server sends data. This data is then, as you say, is viewed on the normal browser. Try debugging and you will be able to see the exact place where the data is fetched. Save this returned data into a variable and pass this variable as the link.